# Take some numbers & find is it prime or not?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    long long n,a,i,f;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    while(n--)
    { 
        f=0;
        scanf("%lld",&a);
        for(i=2;i<=sqrt(a);i++){
             if(a%i==0){
                 f=1;
                 break;            
             }
       }
       if(f==0){
           printf("YES\n");
              }
       else
         printf("NO\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

First line of input is the number of test cases. Maximum number of test cases = 500, 0<=a<=5*10^9.
We have to check whether the numbers are prime or not. If the numbers are prime print `YES` else `NO`.
This is my code and every time get wrong answer while submitting.

```
Sample Input (Plaintext Link)
5

2
3
4
5
6
Sample Output (Plaintext Link)
YES
YES
NO
YES
NO
```

Comment: You need `long long` for large integer values <= `5*10^9`

Comment: try using long long int (or simply long long), on google search the range of long int was 4,294,967,295 which is slightly less than the constraints.

Comment: which input its not working?

Comment: Just to cut down the running time rather than using `sqrt(a)` inside loop, find it outside and store it in a variable and use it in loop

Comment: @user7 compiler will do that :)

Comment: Results seems correct,What problem you have?

Comment: Provide an example that fails.

Comment: @Milind Oh I was not aware of it..

Comment: I have used long long also though it gives wrong output.I got right answer in my laptop.Something is wrong here.

Comment: @RituparnaChakraborty Did you remember to change the `scanf`s to take `%lld` as well?

Comment: You can use a ulong instead of a long.

Comment: @user7 It's still a good suggestion. Not all compilers will optimise the code.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    long long n,a,i,f;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    while(n--)
    { 
    f=0;
     scanf("%lld",&a);
     for(i=2;i<=sqrt(a);i++){
         if(a%i==0){
         f=1;
         break;            
         }
     }
     if(f==0){
              printf("YES\n");
              }
     else
         printf("NO\n");
}
return 0;
}
I have written this now.

Comment: The code is correct. Make sure that your answer is in the correct format. For example, you may need a space instead of a newline character.

Comment: Please add that as an edit to your original question, it's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: I have added.@zenith and the output is in newline @tourniquet_grab.

Comment: @RituparnaChakraborty In which OJ are you doing this? And what about input 1?

Comment: I am doing this in hackerearth @user7

Comment: "0<=n<=5*10^9" Isn't `n` the number of test cases?

Comment: Yes,n is the number of test cases. @tourniquet_grab

Comment: @Rituparna Then "Maximum number of test cases - 500, 0<=n<=5*10^9" does not make sense.

Comment: n must be the number which  must be checked for primality.

Comment: Yes. It should probably be 0<=a<=5*10^9. By the way, the output is correct. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: It's gives wrong answer every time.Don't understand why?@tourniquet_grab

Comment: @Rituparna Since you are submitting it in an OJ you can't find the test case for which it is failing. And unless you provide such a test case you can't really get any help from SO

Comment: @Rituparna Can you provide the link to that problem

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/hack-a-saurus-2-1/algorithm/you-just-went-full-retard-never-go-full-retard-1/

Comment: OH This is an ongoing contest..

Comment: ok.give me some idea..what is going wrong...after this.It will end on 9.00 pm. @user7

Comment: @Rituparna Follow chqrlie's answer.. You must print NO for inputs 1 and 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the test cases fall in the range `0 <= n <= 5*10^9`.  Your algorithm prints `YES` for numbers `0` and `1`.  It should probably print `NO` for each of these, as they are not really prime.  Check the problem specification for these numbers and print the appropriate answer.

Comment: Yes,for 0 & 1 it is printing 'YES'.So,how can I overcome this?

Comment: Instead of `f=0;`, compute `f = a < 2;` just after reading `a` with `scanf("%lld",&a);`

Answer (score -3):

math library must be included when building executable. For Unix/Linux you can compile with `-lm` command.

```
gcc test.c -o test -lm
```

If you are submitting online, you must create your own `sqrt()` function.

Comment: A compile time error would be generated if the function is not available.

Comment: `sqrt()` is defined in `math.h`